# Add subviews to uitableviewcell dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, draw

Alright so I'm trying to do something which seems to be really hard for some reason (in other words can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong/missing)

First I started with writing the `cell` completely in code. This way I did get the required result but the `cell` would not expand to the correct `height`.

Now I've switched to using a `xib` to build the `view`. What I need is the following:

[image]

The blue part would need to be zero in case there are no `subviews` so the `label` and `image` will fill the entire `cell`. When there are subviews they should be added to it and the cell needs to expand to the required height.

Here is the code I wrote to add the subviews to the container.

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        drawSubCells()
    }

    func drawSubCells() {
        // Check if there are subcells
        if let cells = subCells {
            let count = CGFloat(cells.count)

            let contentViewFrame = CGRect(x: self.frame.width * 0.2, y: cell_contentView.frame.origin.y, width: self.frame.width * 0.8, height: 40 * count)
            cell_contentView.frame = contentViewFrame

            var i = 0
            for cell in cells {

                // create a view for each cell
                let cellView = UIView()
                let cellFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: CGFloat(i * 40), width: contentViewFrame.width, height: 40)
                cellView.frame = cellFrame

                // add a image view to each cell
                let imageView = UIImageView(image: cell.cellImage)
                let imageViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (cellFrame.height - cellFrame.height / 2) / 2, width: cellFrame.width * 0.2, height: cellFrame.height / 2)
                imageView.frame = imageViewFrame
                imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

                // add a label to each cell
                let cellLabel = UILabel()
                let cellLabelFrame = CGRect(x: imageViewFrame.width, y: 0, width: cellFrame.width - imageViewFrame.width, height: 40)
                cellLabel.frame = cellLabelFrame
                //cellLabel.font = cell.cellFont
                cellLabel.textColor = cell.cellTextColor
                cellLabel.text = cell.cellText.uppercased()
                cellLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 15

                // add the imageview and label to the subcell view
                cellView.addSubview(imageView)
                cellView.addSubview(cellLabel)

                // add the subcell to the cell
                cell_contentView.addSubview(cellView)
                i += 1
            }
        }
    }
```

however this doesn't work. I think it has to do with my constraints being incorrect in my xib.

I uploaded a project (which is a test project) [here](https://github.com/MaikoHermans/tableCellDynamicHeightProblem). I'm hoping someone will be able to help me out with this. I just can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. You can also find the class where I wrote the entire view programmatically in this project.

Comment: Have you considered using UIStackView? You could add any custom view dynamically from code as a subview to your UIStackView.

Comment: I actually did not think about that at all. I'll give that a shot